# Blender animation export problems

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I've done a lot of imports and exports from Blender to Unreal but I can't seem to find a good solution for my case. It's really important for me that the imported object points into +X direction. Also the Root bone should have 0 transforms and also point in +X direction. Scale should be 1.

In Blender the object and joints point into -Y direction.

I could figure out a way to export the object with the standard blender export settings but then the root bone is scaled to 100. I can get rid of this problem if I scale the object 100 times in Blender and then import it with scale 0,01. This works but is really annoying and costs a lot time to do and sometimes the animation breaks and has to be fixed.

I then bought the better fbx exporter for blender (https://www.blendermarket.com/products/better-fbx-importer--exporter)
and this worked very well and got rid of the scaling problem but I can't seem to find a setting to change the front axis for the object and joints.

So now the question is: Is there another solution to this problem? Maybee an even better export addon? I've wasted a lot of time searching for a solution and would be verry greatfull if anybody could help.

Kind regards